# Prevent default tabbing behavior in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, focus

I have few input fields to update.When press tab key I need move focus to the next field only after success of some validation of the current field. If fails then remain in the same field.

```
function fieldFocus(e, nxFld){
  var key;
  if (window.event) key   = e.keyCode;
  else if (e.which) key = e.which;

  if (!e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

   // do validate {}
    if (success)
     $(nxFld).focus();  //set the focus to the next fld
    else
     //  remain in the same field   
  }
  return false;
}

$(currFld).bind("keydown",function(e) {
   return fieldFocus(e, nxtFld); 
});
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome. But in firefox the default focus always fires before the validation. Please help me on this to prevent that default behavior of the firefox.

---- Edited Code related to @Faizul Hasan's code ----

```
<script>
  function fieldFocus(e, obj){
    var key;
    if (window.event) key   = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) key = e.which;

    if (!e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
      // do validate
      if (0 !== obj.value.length){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?')
        if(answer)
          return true;
        else{
          // need to stop cursor focus to the next field
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
      else{
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

This is where Im getting the real problem, before user confirms the focus moves to next field in firefox. But in IE and Chrome its working fine.

Comment: didnt you try to prevent default then run validation and then manually focus next field?

Comment: TO which event you trigger fieldFocus function?? Is it possible to create jsFiddle with your codes to which event you trigger that function?

Comment: @Faizul Hasan, I have update the code sample.. Sorry I couldnt update it to the jsFiddle. Hope you can understand my requirement..

Comment: I do not think you have to pass the next field. Just try the answer I have posted instead. It is working fine... Hope that would help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few workouts I found something with the Firefox which causes the problem. It is the 'keypress' event.

The 'keypress' event still fires when apply preventdefault() to keydown but only in Firefox.

So I handled the 'keypress' as below and solved my problem.

Hope this will help many others.

```
var browsFix = false;
function fieldFocus(e, nxFld){
  var key;
  if (window.event) key   = e.keyCode;
  else if (e.which) key = e.which;

  if (!e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
    browsFix = true;  
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    // do validate {}
    if (success)
      $(nxFld).focus();  //set the focus to the next fld
    else
    //  remain in the same field   
  }
  return false;
}

$(currFld).bind("keydown",function(e) {
  browsFix = false;
  return fieldFocus(e, nxtFld); 
});

$(currFld).bind("keypress",function(e) {
  if (browsFix)
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
      function fieldFocus(e, obj){
        var key;
        if (window.event) key   = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) key = e.which;

        if (!e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
          // do validate
          if (0 !== obj.value.length){
            return true;
          }
          else{
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="first-field"  onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
  <input type="text" id="second-field" onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
  <input type="text" id="third-field" onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
  <input type="text" id="fourth-field" onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
  <input type="text" id="fifth-field" onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
  <input type="text" id="sixth-field" onkeydown="fieldFocus(event, this);" />
</body>
```

Please note this is a sample code for your reference since the way you fire the function is not mentioned in your code. You can use jQuery to easily call the function for `keydown` event instead of calling it for all input element like `onkeydown = functionName(<params>)`. Hope this would help you.

**Updated: Same code but jQuery integrated**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.input-element').each(function(index, value){
          $(value).keydown(function(event){
            fieldFocus(event, this);
          });
        });

        function fieldFocus(e, obj){
          var key;
          if (window.event) key   = e.keyCode;
          else if (e.which) key = e.which;

          if (!e.shiftKey && key === 9) {
            // do validate                   
            if (0 !== obj.value.length){
              return true;
            }
            else{
              e.stopPropagation();
              e.preventDefault();
            }
           }
          return false;
        }
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="first-field" class="input-element"  />
      <input type="text" id="second-field" class="input-element" />
      <input type="text" id="third-field" class="input-element" />
      <input type="text" id="fourth-field" class="input-element" />
      <input type="text" id="fifth-field" class="input-element" />
      <input type="text" id="sixth-field" class="input-element" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. And I did try your code but could not get what I want.
In My case, the validation part is not that simpler. Sometime It will ask user confirmation with a dialog to validate. Specially on that time I need to handle the focus. Check the code that I added with modification of your code.